# executing a .jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a simple .jar file, when i run this:

```
>java -jar SLA.jar
```

It works correctly, however when i run

```
>SLA.jar
```

Nothing happens at all, i thought that these were meant to be the same the same.

What is going on here, is it something to do with my file associations? how can i set the default program for a .jar to be java -jar and not just java.

Comment: This isn't programming related.

Comment: it should go to superuser, where people will tell you that it depends on your OS and how to do it ;)

Comment: ++ on @Bozho; this is a Superuser question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools | Options | File Associations | Look for JAR | Advanced Options | Edit the "open" action  and use:

```
"C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

well

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

by example, it depends on your JRE location

Comment: I had to change it from javaw to java.exe and then this worked, not sure why i had to change it though, as it should work as you suggested, oh well, i don't mind :)

Comment: Only a guess: I lookup up the reference of javaw and it says: "The javaw command is identical to java, **except that with javaw there is no associated console window**. Use javaw when you don't want a command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some reason." If your program is a console one, when you do ">java ..." it has the current console. When you do ">file.jar" Windows (I guess) doesn't provide one. Then you must use java.exe to ensure there is one.